# How to Perform Inline nested if statement in React Component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ternary-operator

How to perform inline nested if Statement in React View ,

**For example**

```
true ? function a()  : function b()
```

the Above format is working fine but i need to perform nested if like below example

**For Example**

```
true ? true : function a () :  true :function b()
```

**My Working Code**

```
  <div onClick={()=> this.props.materials.is_table_clicked  ? this.handleLocal() : this.props.enableMaterialTable(this.props.materials)}>
```

**Tried Nested If but not Working**

```
<div onClick={()=> this.props.materials.is_table_clicked  ? this.handleLocal() : this.props.audio.playing ? this.props.enableMaterialTable(this.props.materials)}>
```

Comment: I think you should avoid this, you lose so much readability. I'll put this into a dedicated function

Comment: they are newly made changes so i have to follow the same  way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the else condition for nested else.

```
 : (this.props.audio.playing ? 
this.props.enableMaterialTable(this.props.materials):""//You missing this
```

It should work:

```
 <div onClick={()=> this.props.materials.is_table_clicked  ? 
    this.handleLocal() : (this.props.audio.playing ? 
this.props.enableMaterialTable(this.props.materials):"")}>
```

Comment: Dont Work  Ved :(

Comment: Great Ved ... it is the Solution ... :)  Thanks for the time

Comment: Welcome @VickySmart.